# Unicorn acting up on EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, unicorn

I have a medium EC2 instance which seems to corrupt unicorn instances after a few days, causing the application to throw 403 errors with urls showing as `http://app/foo/bar`

"app" is the proxy to unicorn. Here is my site config for nginx

```
    upstream app {
            server unix:/home/foo/app/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }


    server {
            listen   80; # This is on by default. 
            client_max_body_size 2G;
            #       upload_max_file_size 50m;
            server_name foo.tld; # Hostname
            keepalive_timeout 5;
            root /home/foo/app/current/public; # Application root.

            access_log /home/foo/log/foo_access.log; # Logs for nginx access
            error_log /home/foo/log/foo_error.log;

            if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$) {
                    return 405;
            }

            if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
              return 503;
            }

            error_page 503 @maintenance;

            location @maintenance {
              rewrite  ^(.*)$  /system/maintenance.html last;
              break;
            }

            # Static serving as defined in the RoR guides 
            # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production
            location ~ ^/(assets(?!\/(files|pictures)))/ {
                    gzip_static on;
                    expires max;
                    add_header Cache-Control public;
            }       

            # Proxy forwarding to unicorn
            location / {
                    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
                    error_page 404                  /404.html;
                    error_page 422                  /422.html;
                    error_page 500 502 503 504      /500.html;
                    error_page 403                  /403.html;
            }

            location @app {
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_pass http://app;
            }

        location = /favicon.ico {
                expires max;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        location ~ \.php {
                deny all;
        }
    }
```

My unicorn.rb

```
worker_processes 4
working_directory '/home/foo/app/current'

# This loads the application in the master process before forking
# worker processes
# Read more about it here:
# http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html
preload_app true
GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true


timeout 30

# This is where we specify the socket.
# We will point the upstream Nginx module to this socket later on
listen '/home/foo/app/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock', :backlog => 64
pid '/home/foo/app/shared/pids/unicorn.pid'

# Set the path of the log files inside the log folder of the testapp
stderr_path '/home/foo/app/current/log/unicorn.stderr.log'
stdout_path '/home/foo/app/current/log/unicorn.stdout.log'
```

And my cap recipe

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'

set :rvm_ruby_string, ENV['GEM_HOME'].gsub(/.*\//,"") # Read from local system
require "rvm/capistrano"                               # Load RVM's capistrano plugin.

# Application name
set :application, "foo"

# Repo information
set :repository, "foo.git"
set :scm, :git
set :branch, "master"

# Server information
set :user, "foo"
set :scm_passphrase, "foo"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
server "foo.tld", :web, :app, :db # This is our EC2 Instance
set :deploy_to, "/home/foo/app"
ssh_options[:keys] = [File.join(ENV["HOME"], "keys/foo")]
set :use_sudo, false

namespace :deploy do

  desc "Restart of Unicorn"
  task :restart, :excerpt => { :no_release => true } do
    run "kill -a USR2 `cat /home/foo/app/shared/pids/unicorn.pid`"
  end

  desc "Start Unicorn"
  task :start, :excerpt => { :no_release => true } do
    run "cd #{current_path} ; bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D"
  end

  desc "Stop Unicorn"
  task :stop, :excerpt => { :no_release => true } do
    run "kill -s QUIT `cat /home/foo/app/shared/pids/unicorn.pid`"
  end

  namespace :web do
    desc "Throw maintenance page up"
    task :disable do
      require "erb"
      on_rollback { run "rm #{shared_path}/system/maintenance.html" }

      reason = ENV['REASON']
      deadline = ENV['UNTIL']

      template = File.read("./app/views/layouts/maintenance.html.erb")
      result   = ERB.new(template).result(binding)

      put result, "#{shared_path}/system/maintenance.html", :mode => 0644
    end
  end
end
```

Any insight as to why unicorn would act up after a few days? Additionally is there any "gotchas" in my current setup.?

UPDATE:
It looks like unicorn is never able to restart hung up processes

```
E, [2012-07-03T09:59:13.554781 #9521] ERROR -- : worker=3 PID:9656 timeout (31s > 30s), killing
E, [2012-07-03T09:59:13.710103 #9521] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 9656 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=3
I, [2012-07-03T09:59:13.710349 #9521]  INFO -- : worker=3 spawning...
I, [2012-07-03T09:59:13.906277 #16214]  INFO -- : worker=3 spawned pid=16214
I, [2012-07-03T09:59:13.906672 #16214]  INFO -- : worker=3 ready
E, [2012-07-03T13:37:45.158213 #9521] ERROR -- : worker=3 PID:16214 timeout (31s > 30s), killing
E, [2012-07-03T13:37:45.402827 #9521] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 16214 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=3
I, [2012-07-03T13:37:45.403125 #9521]  INFO -- : worker=3 spawning...
I, [2012-07-03T13:37:45.531584 #16270]  INFO -- : worker=3 spawned pid=16270
I, [2012-07-03T13:37:45.531982 #16270]  INFO -- : worker=3 ready
```

Comment: your :backlog is very small in unicorn.rb - default is 1024 - are you sure you only want a backlog of 64?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have preload_app: true, you need to reconnect your database/cache instances upon fork

in before_fork

```
Rails.cache.reset
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
```

in after_fork

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection Rails.env
```

If you have any other memcached/dalli connections, make sure you .reset them as well.  Good luck!